# Set wal_level = logical instead of replica in YugabyteDB?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Is there a way to set `wal_level = logical` instead of replica in YugabyteDB? I’m looking to implement CDC so I can synchronize other systems with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that YugabyteDB doesn’t reuse the PostgreSQL storage engine & replication mechanism, but has built its own. And it doesn’t support setting `wal_level=logical`.

Currently, CDC support is in the works https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/9019.